# Where can i learn algorithms from zero?

Tags: java, algorithms

I've been studying programming for like 3 years or so but my teachers never taught me algorithms.
Are there any online courses for beginners? with tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you have in mind with learning algorithms. I believe you should get yourself a book, where there are usually also some tasks to do at the end of each chapter. If I remember correctly, book "Algorithms and Data Structures" from Niklaus Wirth has tasks at the end of chapters. It has been a long time since I opened it. That one might be outdated, since the programming language used in there is pascal, but exercises can be useful. There are plenty of other books for students. Search for `Algorithms and Data Structures`.

I found this nice course, which does not have tasks: https://www.programiz.com/dsa.
Then you have Khan Academy courses, where you have tasks, too: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/ap-computer-science-principles/algorithms-101.

I am sure you can find more like [here](https://medium.com/javarevisited/10-best-books-for-data-structure-and-algorithms-for-beginners-in-java-c-c-and-python-5e3d9b478eb1). Then start with the one that suits you the best.

Search also for `Algortihms and Data Structures pdf`. You will find many books.